# Round brackets around a person's name

Tags: meaning

My grandson shows his mother’s current partner’s name in round brackets on a genealogy site.  What does the bracketed name mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about highly specific (and possibly idiosyncratic) formatting conventions in a niche subject, rather than any general rule in English.

Comment: Please can you show us the actual text so we can see what you mean? If you don't want to use the person's real name, you can substitute a fake one.

Comment: Brackets around names is not a niche topic at all. Historians, literature academics and others use them quite a bit....

Comment: You should ask your grandson. But to clarify, has the partner changed their name. Is the whole name in brackets or just the surname? The use of round brackets to indicate maiden names is a particular use in genealogy, not in general use.

Answer (score 1):

In English-language genealogy context, parentheses generally indicate prior surnames. My mother is Beverly (Dierlam, Barnard) Sommer. (She's no longer living.) She was Beverly Dierlam at birth, and changed her name to Beverly Barnard at marriage. Her husband died; she remarried to become Beverly Sommer. I see this most commonly with women who changed their name at marriage. Prior to my father's death, Mom's name would have been written as "Beverly Barnard", "Mrs. Gene Barnard", "Beverly (Dierlam) Barnard", or "Beverly Barnard, née Dierlam".

Outside of a genealogy context, I most commonly see the same information using the "née" form - "Beverly (née Dierlam) Barnard".

Note that my experience is primarily with US-based written English. The convention might well be slightly different elsewhere.